# SQL 'GROUP BY' & 'Having' problem on stratascratch

Tags: sql, postgresql, having

The task was - https://platform.stratascratch.com/coding/514-marketing-campaign-success-advanced/official-solution?code_type=1

And I'm a little bit confused in the code.

```
 SELECT user_id
 FROM marketing_campaign
 GROUP BY user_id
 HAVING count(DISTINCT created_at) > 1
    AND count(DISTINCT product_id) > 1)
```

I'm interested in **HAVING**, default code would be like 'select user_id, count(DISTINCT created_at), count(DISTINCT product_id) and something like this, but in this code its added to **HAVING**. Does this mean count(DISTINCT created_at) work in the **ALL DATASET? BUT HOW IF ITS ALREADY GROUP BY** background and then return only user_id which one like this condition?

Comment: For each user_id, check the HAVING clause! I.e. only return user_id's having more than 1 distinct created_at and also more than 1 distinct product_id.

Comment: HAVING claus will do this for the entire original data array, not for the aggregated?

Comment: Please read [mre]

Comment: `HAVING` works per grouping, so in this case per `user_id`